# Overflow menu in Stock Browser

Tags: karbonn

The stock browser in Android doesn't show the menu/ 3dots (Overflow menu) to change the settings at all. I tried about:debug but those 3 dots doesn't come up to change the settings. I use Karbonn Machfive android mobile.